# how to don't skip a line after users imput?

Tags: c++, cin

I wrote a simple program and expected it to work in a certain way, but it doesn't and I just don't know why.

```
for(int i1 = 0; i1 < i; i1++){
    for(int j1 = 0; j1 < j; j1++){
        cout << " {"; cin >>ma[i1][j1]; cout <<"} ";
        }
    cout << endl;
}
```

These lines of code were meant to create an output kinda like this:

```
{users imput} {users imput} {users imput}
{users imput} {users imput} {users imput}
{users imput} {users imput} {users imput}
```

but they result in an output like this:

```
 {users imput
} {users imput
} {users imput
}
{users imput
} {users imput
} {users imput
}
{users imput
} {users imput
} {users imput
}
```

Please can someone help a fellow beginner in this little problem?

Comment: You cannot in the way you are trying to do this. There was a similar question a few days ago, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Cin will read a line in console so that you cannot both write and read on the same line in console. You shoul read all the input and store them in an array or list, vector etc. Then you should make a loop to “cout” them in a format as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i1 = 0; i1 < i; i1++)
  for(int j1 = 0; j1 < j; j1++)
    cin >> ma[i1][j1]; 


for(int i1 = 0; i1 < i; i1++)
{
    for(int j1 = 0; j1 < j; j1++)
        cout << "{" << ma[i1][j1] << "} ";

    cout << endl;
}
```